# Leap year identifier with tense

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that the user enters a year they want.

Then the program tells you if the year is a leap year or not with the tense.

So if the year was 2021, it would say “2021 **will** not be a leap year”

If the year was 2000, it would say” 2000 **was** a leap year”

Here is what I have so far but it doesn’t seem to be working:

```
def is_leap_year(x):
    if x % 4 == 0:
        return True
    if x % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if x % 400 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def leap_year_answer(x):
    if x > 2020 and x % 100 == 0:
        print("Will not be a leap year")
    if x > 2020 and x % 400 == 0:
        print("Will be a leap year")
    if x < 2020 and x % 100 == 0:
        print("Was not a leap year")
    if x < 2020 and x % 400 == 0:
        print("Was a leap year")
    if x == 2020 and x % 400 == 0:
        print("Is a leap year")
    if x == 2020 and x % 100 == 0:
        print("Is not a leap year")

x = int(input("Enter your year: "))
print(leap_year_answer(x))
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't seem to be working'? Does it run? It runs but print the wrong result? Can you please give an example of input and the respective output.

Answer (score 1):

This was my approach to your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import datetime

def is_leapyear(year):
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def print_leapyear(year):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    curr_year = now.year

    if is_leapyear(year):
        if  year >curr_year:
            print(str(year) + " will be a leapyear")
        elif year < curr_year:
            print(str(year) + " was a leapyear")
        else:
            print(str(year) + " is a leapyear")
    else:
        if year > curr_year:
            print(str(year) + " will not be a leapyear")
        elif year < curr_year:
            print(str(year) + " was no leapyear")
        else:
            print(str(year) + " is no leapyear")

year = int(input("Enter your year: "))
print_leapyear(year)
```

Your calculations on how to determine a leapyear are wrong. A leapyear has to be divisible by 4 and not by 100, except when it is divisible by 400. 
I took the function you had to calculate a leapyear and used it in the following function where I determine which tense to print in.
Then instead of hardcoding the current date I used datetime to determine the current date, so this script will be usable after 2020 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `print(f"{year} {verb_tense} {negation} a leap year")` where all this variables are settle (using if clauses) depending on current year and user given year (i.e. your x variable).

Below you can find a bit of code to define that variables:

```
if is_leapyear(year):
    negation = ""
else:
    negation = "not"
if year == current_year:  # get the current year on a previous step
    verb_tense = "is"
else:
    verb_tense = "was"
print(f"{year} {verb_tense} {negation} a leap year")
```

Comment: can you explain further? maybe add a code script to try? @Alfonso

Comment: Sure! You want to write (I will put the variables between square brakes and with slashes I will separate the possible values):
"Year [XXXX] [is/was] [not/  ] a leap year"
so based on my code above:


`print(f"{year} {verb_tense} {negation} a leap year")`




Why not define this variables before?.
(I added the code to my answer above)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the is_leap_year function doesn’t seem to be called. However, in the leap_year_answer function I think there may have been a mistake with how you are calculating wether or not there is a leap year. The calculation to check the year is not a leap year I think should be: if x % 4 !=0. Also the calculation to check if it is a leap year I think should be if x % 4 == 0.

Try this:

```
def leap_year_answer(x):
    if x > 2020 and x % 4 != 0:
        print("Will not be a leap year")
    if x > 2020 and x % 4 == 0:
        print("Will be a leap year")
    if x < 2020 and x % 4 != 0:
        print("Was not a leap year")
    if x < 2020 and x % 4 == 0:
        print("Was a leap year")
    if x == 2020 and x % 4 == 0:
        print("Is a leap year")
    if x == 2020 and x % 4 != 0:
        print("Is not a leap year")

x = int(input("Enter your year: "))
print(leap_year_answer(x))
```

Comment: can you a add a script for me to try with either a fixed version for "if x % 4 !=0, or by calling the is_leap_year function? @AymanElJacifi

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `is_leap_year()` function will not work correctly. For example for the year 1900 it will evaluate, that this year was a leap year, because it evaluates the first `if` statement to `True`. Your `if` clauses must be nested to check the right thing (If year is divisible by 4, check if its also divisible by 100. If it is divisible by 100, also check if it is divisible by 400):

```
def is_leap_year(x):
    if x % 4 == 0:
        if x % 100 == 0:
            if x % 400 == 0:
                return True
            else: 
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

To go on with the suggestion of @Alfonso, which i also favor, you can create a much simpler and clearer function `leap_year_answer` by using f-strings, e.g. similar to this:

```
def leap_year_answer(x):
    year = x
    verb_tense = "is" if year==2020 else ("was" if year<2020 else "will be")
    negation = "" if is_leap_year(year) else "not " 
    print(f"{year} {verb_tense} {negation}a leap year")
```